# Почему ставится двоеточие в простом предложении, где при однородных членах нет обобщающего слова?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Для обслуживания аграрного сектора экономики необходимы: дорожные организации, кредитная система, инвестиционные компании и многие другие системы и организации.
По структуре простые предложения могут быть: двусоставными и односоставными, полными и неполными, распространёнными и нераспространёнными.
Мы должны беречь: архитектурные сооружения, произведения скульптуры и живописи, предметы древности, все творения рук человеческих, имеющих ценность с точки зрения истории и культуры.

Почему ставится двоеточие в простом предложении, где при однородных членах нет обобщающего слова?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Двоеточие в подобных предложениях ставится по следующему правилу.

> 3. Если однородным членам предложения не предшествует обобщающее слово (словосочетание), то перед ними двоеточие ставится только в том случае, **когда необходимо предупредить читателя, что дальше следует перечисление:** *Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и ещё какие-то привлекательные узелки и коробочки* (Л. Т.); *Тут были: Павел, чухонец, штабс-капитан Ярошевич, фельдфебель Максименко, красная фуражка, дама с белыми зубами, доктор* (Ч.). Ср. в деловой и научной речи: *На заседании присутствовали:…; Для получения смеси нужно взять:…; Роли исполняют:…; В ролях:…*

См.: [**Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103) (Розенталь).